# Idioms or phrases to describe stranger

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

Are there any idioms or phrases to best replace the word **stranger** in the context of the following sentence:

> There was no evidence against the accused. He appears to be a complete stranger to the  victim's entire narrative under oath

Comment: Where did you find the sentence? If you made it up, can you explain what you intended to say in other words?

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty i intend to write the sentence. The context is, the victim, in his evidence adduced no evidence at all agaisnt the accused. Given the account, there was no evidence agaisnt the accused. The accused is therefore a stranger to the victim's evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **"stranger"** is fine in context. If you wanted to be more literal, you could say -- I think this is what you or whoever wrote that sentence means -- *"There was nothing in the victim's testimony that identified the defendant as the guilty person."*

Two quibbles:

> 1.This sounds like it's discussing a court case. If so, we generally say **"the victim's testimony"** rather than **"narrative"**. Unless you've already used the word **"testimony"** and you're trying to vary it up.
> 2.**"Under oath"**. I presume the intended meaning is **"the victim's narrative that was given under oath"**. But as worded the sentence is awkward, and possibly ambiguous whether you mean that the victim's story was given under oath or that the stranger is under oath.